# How to update a binary file?

Tags: python

I am reading file in binary mode using python and it is working perfectly. I tried to update the content and the save it into a new file. The code's below:

```
def main():
    f = open("inputFile", "rb")
    myFile = f.read()
    outFile = myFile
    for i in range(0, len(myFile)):
        d1 = myFile[i] + 1
        outFile[i] = d1
    f2 = open("otFile", "wb")
    f2.write(outFile)
    f2.close()
```

The error is:

```
outFile[i] = d1
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

I tried

```
outFile[i] = bytes(d1)
```

I've got this error:

```
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Item assignment on bytes object in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934624/item-assignment-on-bytes-object-in-python)

Comment: A binary if is _encoded_. So you need to specify how the number value should be encoded.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string

Answer (score 0):

Use bytearray() to convert the infile which gives the functionality of both reading and writing as well

```
def main():
    f = open("infile", "rb")
    myFile = f.read()
    outFile = bytearray(myFile)
    for i in range(0, len(myFile)): 
        d1 = myFile[i] + 1
        outFile[i] = d1
    f2 = open("outfile", "wb")
    f2.write(outFile)
    f2.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just to something like this:

```py
def main():
    f = open("inputFile", "rb")
    myFile = f.read()
    f.close()
    outFile = myFile
    for i in range(0, len(myFile)):
        d1 = myFile[i] + 1
        outFile += bytes(d1)
    f2 = open("otFile", "wb")
    f2.write(outFile)
    f2.close()

main()
```