# Python bytes increment

Tags: python

`type(request)`

return 'bytes',

```
type(request[5])
```

returns 'int'
When I try to this

```
request[5] = request[5] + 1
```

I get this error:

```
    request[5] = request[5] + 1
TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment
```

How to increase "1" this member of bytes ?

Comment: Note that representing individual ``bytes`` as numbers is merely a throwback to earlier models of working with raw data. Individual ``bytes`` do not represent actual numbers on which numeric operations make sense – for example, ``b"\xff"[0]+1`` does *not* produce valid ``bytes`` data. Is there a reason why you need to perform such operations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Item assignment to bytes object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934624/item-assignment-to-bytes-object)

Comment: `request = request[:5] + bytes((request[5] + 1,)) + request[6:]`

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is to change the value of a byte type data.
`byte` can NOT be modified. But you can modified it after making it into a `bytearray`.
To do so:

```
by = b'abcd\x65'
print(b'abcde')
print(type(by))
# b'abcde'
# <class 'bytes'>
bytearray(b'bbcde')
barr = bytearray(by)
print(barr[0])
print(type(barr[0]))
# 97
# <class 'int'>
barr[0] = barr[0]+1
print(barr)
# bytearray(b'bbcde')
```